# Fitnesse Framework regular expressions possible?

Tags: java, regex, fitnesse, fit-framework

Is there an easy way in [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) to check cells based on regex patterns? This should work for all the possible fixtures like "query table", "decision table" and so on. E.g. if results(rows) are returned from a query table it should be possible to match certain cells (columns) against a regex, not just a fixed string. I guess you know what I mean. I can't find any hint in the docs and googling around I can't find a solution that works out of the box. Is there really no default way in [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) to do this? I can't imagine people haven't asked for this multiple times. If not could someone point me to an online tutorial somewhere?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slim table style supports regular expressions for value comparisons using the syntax

`=~/regex/`

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.ValueComparisons for more information.

Comment: Oh, we have a bit older FitNesse.jar - regexes should appear from 201003** builds...

Answer (score 1):

In the Java world, there is no "out-of-the-box" way to do this.  With the .NET version, it's available: http://syterra.com/Fit/RegExHandler.html

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. do you know of any tutorial that explains how to implement such functionality?

Comment: I haven't worked much with the Java code for FitNesse and I haven't seen this discussed anywhere.  Sorry, not much help for you.